# How to combine in xpath "." and "()"

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have a table in DOM, e.g.:

```
<div class="test-table">
  <div class="ant-collapse ant-collapse-icon-position-start test-table-composer">
    <div class="ant-collapse-item ant-collapse-item-active">
      <div class="ant-collapse-header" role="button" />
      <div class="ant-collapse-content ant-collapse-content-active" >
        <div class="ant-collapse-content-box">
          <div class="ant-collapse ant-collapse-icon-position-start test-table-composer">
            <div class="ant-collapse-item ant-collapse-item-active">
              <div class="ant-collapse-header" role="button" />
              <div class="ant-collapse-content ant-collapse-content-active" >
                <div class="ant-collapse-content-box">
                  <div class="ant-collapse ant-collapse-icon-position-start test-table-composer">
                    <div class="ant-collapse-item">
                      <div class="ant-collapse-header" role="button"/>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="test-table-test-group">
                    <div class="ant-collapse ant-collapse-icon-position-start test-table-test-item analyzed incomplete">
                      <div class="ant-collapse-item" id="c2c2c3b6-8b72-11ed-9e2e-0f23ae4a2524">
                        <div class="ant-collapse-header" role="button"/>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ant-collapse ant-collapse-icon-position-start test-table-test-item analyzed incomplete">
                      <div class="ant-collapse-item" id="c2c2c3b7-8b72-11ed-9e2e-8ba095d9d02e">
                        <div class="ant-collapse-header" role="button"/>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ant-collapse ant-collapse-icon-position-start test-table-test-item analyzed incomplete">
                      <div class="ant-collapse-item" id="c6248c66-8b72-11ed-9e2e-0b95f6f4ea18">
                        <div class="ant-collapse-header" role="button"/>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ant-collapse ant-collapse-icon-position-start test-table-test-item analyzed incomplete">
                      <div class="ant-collapse-item" id="c6466c47-8b72-11ed-9e2e-cd2c87901141">
                        <div class="ant-collapse-header" role="button"/>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ant-collapse ant-collapse-icon-position-start test-table-test-item analyzed incomplete">
                      <div class="ant-collapse-item" id="c4c28b5f-8b72-11ed-9e2e-496585fd7ed6">
                        <div class="ant-collapse-header" role="button"/>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="test-table-test-group"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and have my xpath:

```
(//div[contains(@class, 'test-table-composer')]/div[contains(@class, 'test-table-test-item') or (contains(@class, 'ant-collapse-item') and not(@id))])[%s]
```

and I have a library which adds a "." to the beginning of the expression.
[%s] is used for adding indexes

How can I correctly update my current xpath to work with a "."?
I need parentheses because it can be several nested elements with my xpath and I need to find them all and have a possibility to add an index inside it

Comment: If someone is adding "." to the start of your path, then you're constrained to use a path that starts with "/" or "//". No way around it. In 2.0 you could put a "/" at the start (`/(//x)[1])` is valid) -- but not in XPath 1.0, which Selenium is still using after 23 years.

Comment: Thanks. Then will try to change my current xpath somehow to remove parenthesses from the beggining

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can put the dot `.` before the first `//` so your XPath will be

```java
(.//div[contains(@class, 'test-table-composer')]/div[contains(@class, 'test-table-test-item') or (contains(@class, 'ant-collapse-item') and not(@id))])[%s]
```

otherwise it will not work

Comment: The dot is adding via string concatenation, like `"." + String.format(xpath, index)`
Will try to change my xpath. 
But thanks for the answer

Comment: You can not just add it infront of the entire expression, it should be added inside the string

Comment: I understand, that in front of string it will not work. 
But as I mentioned in the description - this is doing by library, it's not my code. So, I can't change this behavior